# Node.js safari push notifications intermittent signature failure

Tags: node.js, signature, pkcs#7, safari-push-notifications

I am using the [safari-push-notifications v 0.3.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/safari-push-notifications) module to create the push package required for Safari. Occasionally I get the error `Signature verification of push package failed` from Safari.

I noticed in the failed signatures there are some garbled/invalid characters. I tried taking these out and using the signature, but it still fails.

My cert, key, intermediate, and manifest are the same each time.

Most of the time the signature works just fine, but once in a while it fails.

Has anybody else experienced this and know a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had opened an issue in the github repo for this problem as well, and the owner pushed a fix. If you are experiencing this problem, just upgrade to version 0.3.1 or higher.